# How can I solve this raised to 5 equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am struggling to solve this equation on order to i. Can anyone help me? Maybe show step by step how to solve it so I can understand?

[image]

EDIT: "i" may or may not be a complex number (I am trying to solve it in C)

Thanks

Comment: What is $ i $? An integer?

Comment: "i" may or may not be a real number, I am trying to solve it in C

Answer (score 1):

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=49000%3D1950*(1-(1%2Bx)%5E-5)%2Fx%2B50000%2F(1%2Bx)%5E5) finds five roots, approximately $0.0435373, 0.689656 \pm 0.954798 i,-1.81221 \pm 0.590139 i$ where my $i$ is $\sqrt {-1}$, not your $i$